# Difference between Fluid and Fluid Grid design CSS

Tags: css, layout, grid

I can't establish the difference between Fluid and Fluid Grid design. Arguably any elements in a fluid layout will share a lowest common denominator, so surely any layout is a grid based on the LCD.

Comment: its for my question in comment than i delete that  question other user delete answer ... so part only remaining is how stupid i am .....lol

Comment: idk but might help The main difference is that Fluid Layouts are based on proportionally laying out your website so elements take up the same percent of space on different screen sizes, while Responsive Design uses CSS Media Queries to present different layouts based on screen sizes/type of screen. For some examples of both kinds of design,

Answer (score 1):

Grid based layout is based on the use of pre-defined 'columns' which are used to set the width of elements on the page.

As you are probably aware, a fluid layout is something that will proportionaly adjust to the browser width.  This still hold true with fluid grid systems with the added advantage of also using columns.

Grid layouts come with added advantages over standard (or non-grid) layouts:

- design consistency
- rapid, easy layout development
- encourages correlation and consistency between different page elements
- helps produce a visualy balanced layout
- usualy allow for flexibility in terms of setting number of columns, gutters, etc.

Fluid grid systems are just a grid system with a fluid style (the column widths are proportional rather than fixed).

If you do not already use grid based layouts then I can definatly recommend getting into them!

Some refs for you:

- (fixed grid) http://960.gs/
- (fluid grid) http://www.tinyfluidgrid.com/
- (fixed, fluid, fixed grid, fluid grid) http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem